# If Else not working in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

If is never working. Always falling in else condition. I have debugged and checked @nextapprover is not null.

```
IF (@nextApprover != NULL)
BEGIN
    UPDATE CallWatching
    SET EmployeeNo = @employeeNo
    WHERE @SRFID = MasterCode;

    INSERT INTO CallForwarding (
        MasterCode
        ,EmployeeNo
        ,ApproverNo
        ,IsForwarded
        ,ForwardBy
        )
    VALUES (
        @SRFID
        ,@EmployeeNo
        ,@nextApprover
        ,0
        ,@EmployeeNo
        )
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE CallWatching
    SET STATUS = 1
    WHERE @SRFID = MasterCode;
END
```

Comment: Use `IS NOT NULL` instead of `!= NULL`.

Comment: @NaveenN, how is that any different?

Comment: If You compare something to null, then the result is always false. Regardless of what kind of comparison You use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `IS NOT NULL`

i.e. Change: `if(@nextApprover!=null)`
to `IF(@nextApprover IS NOT NULL)`

Additionally you should `<>` instead of `!=` as it is ANSI compliant